# How was the Ditto able to send a text message?

Tags: pokemon, pokemon-detective-pikachu

When Pikachu and Tim go to the underground Pokemon Arena, they are immediately spotted by Ms. Norman, who sends a message to someone:

> Eventually revealed to be Howard Clifford, revealing that Ms. Norman is Howard's Ditto.

One of the themes of the movie is that Pokemon and humans are not able to communicate, the Pokemon can feel what the humans desire and try to act on it. But in this instance, we clearly see that Ms. Norman (a Ditto) can communicate, at least via written language. Is this some special exception for Dittos, or a goof on the part of the film makers?

Comment: Mr Mime seems perfectly capable of communication, as does MewTwo

Comment: @Valorum Only if you consider miming communication... I guess MewTwo is special because it is a telepath.

Comment: He was miming specific words as well as general actions.

Comment: Being a Mime is an abomiation.

Comment: Well that's certainly true.

Comment: @JackBNimble Been a while for me, but couldn't Meowth straight up talk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's stated [in the film](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=33912) that the Ditto is a genetic experiment and thus would have extra / unique capabilities:

> What kind of a Ditto was that?
>
> That was one of my father's genetic experiments.

[image: Tim and Howard's son]